# Saving small numpy array as a large image

Tags: python, arrays, image

I have a small binary numpy array X

eg.

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1,0],
 [0,0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I save it to an image using

```
plt.imsave('file.png', X, cmap=cm.gray)
```

the only problem is that the image is tiny at 5x5 resolution. How could I increase the resolution of the image while still keeping the information in the image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyPNG](https://github.com/drj11/pypng/) Library. It can be very simple with this library like

```
import png
png.from_array(X, 'L').save("file.png")
```

You can also use `scipy` like following

```
import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('file.png', X)
```

Comment: The image is still tiny, only 5x5 in this case. I want to enlarge the image I am saving while retaining information

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Numpy` to maximize the dimension of your array and increase the number of ones around each index respectively:

```
In [48]: w, h = a.shape

In [49]: new_w, new_h = w * 5, h * 5

In [50]: new = np.zeros((new_w, new_h))

In [51]: def cal_bounding_square(x, y, new_x, new_y):
             x = x * 5 
             y = y * 5
             return np.s_[max(0, x-5):min(new_x, x+5),max(0, y-5):min(new_y, y+5)]
   ....: 

In [52]: one_indices = np.where(a)

In [53]: for i, j in zip(*one_indices):
             slc = cal_bounding_square(i, j, new_w, new_h)
             new[slc] = 1
   ....:
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using a simply numpy hack. Resize the array and fill it with zeros.

1. Consider X as your present numpy array

   ```
   X = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,1,0,0],
                 [0,1,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,1,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0]])
   ```
2. Making a new array of zeros with the required dimensions

   ```
   new_X = np.zeros((new_height,new_width))
   ```
3. Add your original array to it

   ```
   new_X[:X.shape[0], :X.shape[1]] = X
   ```
4. new_X is required array, now save it using any method you like.

Answer (score 0):

An image that has more pixels will hold more information, but the pixels could be redundant. You could make a larger image in which each rectangle is black or white:

```
your_data = [[0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]]
def enlarge(old_image, horizontal_resize_factor, vertical_resize_factor):
    new_image = []
    for old_row in old_image:
        new_row = []
        for column in old_row:
            new_row += column*horizontal_resize_factor
        new_image += [new_row]*vertical_resize_factor
    return new_image
# Make a 7x7 rectangle of pixels for each of your 0 and 1s
new_image = enlarge(your_data, 7, 7)
```